# Malicious malware on phone. How can I make it like new again?

Tags: applications, root-access, factory-reset

I have ran multiple anti-virus apps

I have factory reset my phone.

Probably gained root access.

I know I will probably have to reinstall the OS.

I have upgraded to android 6.0 (marshmellow) but still see signs of infection.

If there are other components to my device that can be used to hide the malwares "rescue" component(s) please let me know.

Samsung Note 5 Verizon
Model: SM-N920V

[image: System info]

[image: System info]

Comment: Could you mention the symptoms of the infection? Nowadays, some malwares are persisted as system apps that makes factory reset useless, but without knowing the symptoms, we can't suggest anything other than "reflash the OS".

Comment: The things that happen are really beyond explanation and me trying to explain them would really just make me sound insane.

Comment: I just need to know how to make every single piece of my phone that an infection can get into or be used to "rescue" the infection after that

Comment: I will say that whatever is on my device is being used to disrupt my life and seems to provide someone the ability to use my phone as if it were their's.

Comment: you need to describe what exactly is wrong with your phone, otherwise it is hard for anyone to know the root cause!

Comment: You won't sound insane if you tell us the symptoms. It will just help. Apart from that, saying "probably gained root access" implies that you haven't. You are usually fully conscious of what you are doing when rooting. My wild guess for fixing is reflashing ROM

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is truly unrecoverable, your last resort would be to back up your phone with Samsung Smart Switch in Backup and Reset option in Settings, then resetting the whole phone (Also in Backup and reset) to factory new. This will get rid of **everything**, and so should only be used as a last resort.

Otherwise, state the symptoms you see on your phone, we will try to help.